# Excel Vlookup macro with range and 2 workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I would like a to make a macro to run vlookup from the last row filled.
The following code is to get the last row to be filled (column J) and the last row filled (column A), the following formula is to get the last rows of this 2 columns;

```
Sub lookup()
'Find the last Row with data in a Column
'In this example we are finding the last row of column A (Filled) and J (to be filled)
    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim lastRowJ As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowJ = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox lastRowA & "   " & lastRowJ

End Sub
```

The **vlookup** looks for the value in column **C** and look in the range in another excel file **C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E**. See picture of the [File](http://chiham.com/gustavochiham/vlook.png)
Will need help with the vlookup please.

Comment: If you were to do it manually what would the formula look like?

Comment: =vlookup(C40846,'C:\LINKED\[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E,3,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? (Untested)

You can write your formula

```
"=vlookup(C40846,'C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E,3,0)"
```

as

```
"=vlookup(C" & "40846" & ",'C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E,3,0)"
```

So all you have to do is replace the last row :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim sFormulaPre As String
    Dim sFormulaSuff As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '=vlookup(C40846,'C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E,3,0)
    sFormulaPre = "=vlookup(C"
    sFormulaSuff = ",'C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E,3,0)"

    With ws
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        MsgBox sFormulaPre & lastRowA & sFormulaSuff
        '~~> Usage
        '.Cells(1, 1).Formula = sFormulaPre & lastRowA & sFormulaSuff
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I run it but didnt fill the rows from 40847 to 40854 :(

Comment: Where and how are you putting the formula?

Comment: I want to wun the formula on the range from the last row of Column J +1 to the last row of column A. That will give me the range from 40847 to 40854.

Comment: No I mean where do you want to put the formula `"=vlookup(C40846,'C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIVE'!$C:$E,3,0)"`? In which sheet and in which cell?

Comment: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW") already edit that, the sheet is called RAW

Comment: And in which cell do you want that formula in?

Comment: I try this and its working:
`Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim lastRowJ As Long
    Dim sFormula As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW")
    sFormula = ",'C:\LINKED[Roster_Iloilo.xlsx]ACTIV'!$C:$E,3,0)"
    With ws
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowJ = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MsgBox "=vlookup(C" & lastRowA & sFormula
      
        .Cells(lastRowJ, 10).Formula = "=vlookup(C" & lastRowA & sFormula
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: `.Cells(lastRowJ, 10).Formula = "=vlookup(C" & lastRowA & sFormula` So is it solved?